# How do I check for error messages in WooCommerce with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Following code changes the "Place Order" button text into: "Please Wait" while the order is processing.

The problem is that if an error message is returned after the button is clicked, the text will still be "Please Wait".

If an error message comes in, the text should revert to "Place Order".
How do I check for the error messages?

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_jquery_script' );
function custom_checkout_jquery_script() {
  if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery( function($){
      jQuery('form.checkout').on('submit', function(event) {
        jQuery('button#place_order').text('Please Wait');
        event.preventDefault();
      });
  });
</script>
 <?php
  endif;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Adam error on checkout error detected by using woocommerce JS event 'checkout_error', just use this jquery code below 'submit' event and all set button text changes to "place order"
for more checkout js events please refer here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/342148/list-of-js-events-in-the-woocommerce-frontend

```
        jQuery( document.body ).on( 'checkout_error', function(){
                console.warn("error occured!");
                jQuery('button#place_order').text('Place Order');
        } );
```

So your code should be like this

```
        add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_jquery_script' );
        function custom_checkout_jquery_script() {
          if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
        ?>
          <script type="text/javascript">
          jQuery( function($){
              jQuery('form.checkout').on('submit', function(event) {
                jQuery('button#place_order').text('Please Wait');
                event.preventDefault();
              });
          });
    
         //To detect woocommerce error trigger JS event
          jQuery( document.body ).on( 'checkout_error', function(){
                    console.warn("error occured!");
                    jQuery('button#place_order').text('Place Order');
            } );

</script>
 <?php
  endif;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You can refer now if any queries please comment.

Comment: Hi @RahulRanjan, I have just tested the code and it does not change the button text back, if there is an error message. Could you advise how to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Hi @AdamAlleman can you share a screenshot of your code? which theme are you using maybe it get conflicts, are you getting the "error occurred!" text in the console?

Comment: Hi @RahulRanjan, the code is exactly as your final code.

Comment: Hi @RahulRanjan, the code is exactly as your final code. This is the HTML of the error message: `<div class="stripe-source-errors" role="alert"><ul class="woocommerce_error woocommerce-error wc-stripe-error"><li>The card number is incomplete.</li></ul></div>` and this is what I see at the sources https://i.imgur.com/SSFqCtW.png if I click on the "Your card number is incomplete" JS message in the console: https://i.imgur.com/YjQvubH.png . There are 2 kind of error messages, not valid card number or incomplete number, sometimes session timeout. But only the text changes, error classes are same.

Comment: @RahulRanjan checkout_error can only happen after the validation, so it's not happening yet, so it cannot be detected

Comment: There is no "error occured!" message in my console, the message is: Your card number is incomplete. But if I replace the text, changing the text back still doesn't work. In fact, what I need is removing the added class, not changing back the text. Because removing the class will change back the text but the syles as well.

Comment: @AdamAlleman  Not sure why it's not working for you, because I tested on my local server this code working for me. You added code in Active theme Functions.php, right?

Comment: Hi @RahulRanjan, yes I added it to my child theme. Do I need a different code for the child theme? But the addition of the class and changing the text does work. Only the removal of the class or reverting the text doesn't work. So that's probably because the error event is not correctly detected. Maybe your error event is not the same as mine? This is a Stripe card payment. You also tested with a Stripe card payment error? So it's both a Stripe error and a Woocommerce error.

Comment: Hi @AdamAlleman sorry, I didn't check with stripe let me check and update here ASAP.